# Explicit void pointer as function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, void-pointers

I have a function:

```
int foo(void * ptr)
{
   // ...
}
```

Can I syntactically (not with compiler warnings, etc.) in C++11/14 disable passing there pointers other than `void *` itself?

For example, now it can be called like:

```
foo(new int(42));
```

I need to disable this.

Comment: And what would be the purpose of that? What would stop someone from doing e.g. `void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new int(42)); foo(ptr);`? Can you please elaborate on the use-case, on the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need an "explicit" void parameter, like in class constructors. If a user reinterpreting it **explicitly**, it's his right. Actual problem: imagine smart pointer, some analogue of `std::unique_ptr`, which allows `void*` to hold, but only for `void *` params passed to constructor.

Comment: Then how about using templates and [type-traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types#Type_traits_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg May be it's a variant, can you help me: how method of templated class may be disabled, and disabling based on template parameters?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's a really silly argument. It's like saying there's no point in disallowing `intptr_t` either, because anyone could just `reinterpret_cast` it to `void*` and back. Type checks are safety features, not security features.

Comment: @Mehrdad Compile-time checks is not to prevent special hacks, but to avoid Murphy's law :-) I.e. to avoid accidental errors. If you specially write `reinterpret_cast` or smth like it, than you understand what you doing.

Comment: vladon: I think you're telling me the same thing I was trying to tell @Joachim...

Comment: @vladon: No worries. Also, don't forget to take a look at my answer below. You don't need C++11 to get compile-time checking (despite claims to the contrary in the top answer).

Comment: A function that takes `void*` and nothing else is very unlikely to be able to do something meaningful, because it doesn't even know the size of the data to work with.

Comment: @alfC the snow is white, and the rain is wet, and 2+2=4. Thank you.

Comment: @vladon, thank you for the poem, the point is that forcing a pointer argument to be exactly `void*` is a code smell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn the function to a template one, then use a `static_assert` and `std::is_void` from `type_traits`:

```
template<typename T>
int foo(T *ptr) {
    static_assert(std::is_void<T>::value, "!");
   // ....
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a `std::enable_if_t` on the return type:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<T>::value, int>
foo(T *ptr) {
    // ....
    return 0;
}
```

And so on, other interesting solutions have already been proposed by other users with their answers.

Here is a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
int foo(T *ptr) {
    static_assert(std::is_void<T>::value, "!");
    // ....
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    void *p = &i;
    foo(p);
    // foo(&i); // compile error
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I suppose there are many other ways of doing it.

Using template functions is simple (it works with C++98 too)

```
template <typename X>
int foo (X * ptr);

int foo (void * ptr)
 { return 1; }

int main()
 {
   int  i;
   void * vp = &i;

   foo(vp);  // OK
   foo(&i);  // linker error

   return 0;
 }
```

As pointed by frymode, the preceding solution give a linker error, not a compiler error, and it's better to get a compiler error.

Using `delete` (from C++11) we can get a compiler error by using this instead:

```
template <typename X>
int foo (X ptr) = delete;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I love it when someone bends the resolution rules to their benefit :)

Comment: This gives linker error not compiler making it much more annoying to find error source.

Comment: @frymode - you're right; thanks; modified my answer with another example that give a compiler error (but only starting from C++11)

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of [pedantic pointer idiom](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1553). Your code should look as bellow. It makes use of the fact that there is no implicit conversions at the higher that one level of indirection:

[[live]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24d9e3857f334889)

```
int foo_impl(void * ptr, void **)
{
   return 0;
}

template <typename T>  
void foo(T* t)  
{  
  foo_impl(t, &t);  
}  

int main()
{
    void* pv;
    foo(pv);
    //foo(new int(2)); // error: error: invalid conversion from 'int**' to 'void**'
}
```

Comment: Nice trick! But I wouldn't be surprised if it messed with optimizations in some cases.

Comment: @Mehrdad `void foo_impl(void *ptr)` could be used; the call has many options e.g. `static_cast<void **>(&t), foo_impl(t);`. Compiler should be able to cope with that

Answer (score 10):

If you want exact type match you can use [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) with [std::is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, void*>::value>>
int foo(T value)
{
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    // return foo(new int(42)); // error: no matching function for call to 'foo(int*)'
    return foo((void*)(new int(42)));
}
```

Comment: This guard is a weak one. See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/jL7Ays), one can easily work around it with a `foo<int*, void>(new int(42));`.

Comment: Use `template <typename T, typename..., typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, void*>::value>>` instead and it won't be possible anymore.

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic way would be to create a new type to represent `void*` to avoid the problem you are describing. Many advocates of good C++ practices suggest creating types to avoid any doubt about what should be passed in and also avoid the compiler letting you.

```
class MyVoid
{
//... implement in a way that makes your life easy to do whatever you are trying to do with your void* stuff
};

int foo(MyVoid ptr)
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## You don't need C++11 to ensure a compile-time error:

```
template<class> struct check_void;

template<> struct check_void<void> { typedef void type; };

template<class T> typename check_void<T>::type *foo(T *ptr) { return ptr; }
 
int main()
{
    foo(static_cast<void *>(0));  // success
    foo(static_cast<int *>(0));  // failure
}
```